# Modelling language to represent folder structure

Tags: data-modeling, directory-structure

Is there a modelling language that can represent file structures?

I've seen examples like the one below, does it have a name? Is there a standardized format?

```
+-- file.txt
+-- folder
|   +-- image.jpg
|   +-- nested
|       +-- program.exe
+-- index.html
```

---

Edit: This question is **not** seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, or other programs. It is asking if there is a name for the specified data format.

Comment: Do you want to display it using Markdown?

Comment: @MatheusAlves Markdown does not define such a format. Are you referring to any extensions?

Comment: I know it doesn't but I discovered that you can run the tree command on your terminal/cmd, copy the output, and past it inside a code block of type text. It'll do the trick

Comment: I think this can help you out [How to display Directory & File structure in Markdown Files](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/markdown-display-directory-and-file-structure)

Comment: Thanks @MatheusAlves! I suppose "`tree` format" partially answers the question, though I don't know if my example has a specific name then.

Comment: No problem! I turned my comments into an answer. See the recommended VS Code extension I just discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the language, my conclusion is that there isn't a specific one. The tree seems to be just a textual representation of the file structure.

Now, supposing you are using Markdown, this is the simplest way to do that:

1. Open the directory on a terminal
2. Run the `tree` command to show its contents as a tree
3. Copy the output
4. In your Markdown editor, create a code block by typing three backticks followed by the word "text" (the way to create a code block may vary slightly from one editor to another)
5. Past the output

**Note**: I'm considering a linux environment. The `tree` command may have a different equivalent for other OSs.

Also, if you want to customize the output, take a look at this tutorial: [How to display Directory & File structure in Markdown Files](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/markdown-display-directory-and-file-structure).

Furthermore, if you are a VS Code user, there is an extension for generating the directory tree for different targets (Markdown, LaTeX and ASCII). See [file-tree-to-text-generator](https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/vscode-file-tree-to-text-generator).